# Valet status is showing "is stopped"

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, laravel-valet

I have a windows 10 insider build, and I am trying to install [cpriego/valet-linux](https://cpriego.github.io/valet-linux/#installation) using `wsl2`

I have installed composer, php and all other the requirements.
Now when I do `valet start` then `valet status` it shows me `nginx Is Stopped` `fpm is stopped`. See the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status message is in a slightly different format on WSL and without the tweaks that are in the WSL specific fork of valet getting a status of services through valet will not work. see [valeryan/valet-wsl merge request 4](https://github.com/valeryan/valet-wsl/pull/4/files) for the changes that have to be made for status detection within wsl using valet.